# VS2013 MVC - Display name not working on some fields

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, data-annotations

Just getting started with MVC.

I have a model and have created a metadata class for persistent data annotations. Some of them work and some don't.

[image: ScreenShot]

As you can see from the screen shot, the JobNo displayName isn't working, but the VersionRef is. Can't figure out why.

Anyone got any ideas? main difference is that Jobno from a related table

After some more investigation, it seems that for some reason the scaffolded .cshtml contains a literal string for any fields that from related tables.

```
<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Job</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.JobNo, "JobNo", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("JobNo", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.JobNo, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

Is there a raeson for this?

Regards

mark

Comment: Can you show the cshtml as well?

Comment: If you use `<div>JobNo</div>` it won't use your metadata...

Comment: I checked the cshtml and posted details in question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some more investigation, it seems that for some reason the scaffolded .cshtml contains a literal string for any fields that from related tables.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried this?
**[DisplayAttribute(Name="Full Name")]  OR    [DisplayName("Full Name")]**

You can check this link: [Example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/775220/ASP-Net-MVC-What-are-the-uses-of-Display-DisplayNa)

Answer (score 2):

According to this:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh833698%28v=vs.118%29.aspx

You are using the overload of `LabelFor` with the `labelText` parameter.

```
public static MvcHtmlString LabelFor<TModel, TValue>(
    this HtmlHelper<TModel> html,
    Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression,
    string labelText,
    IDictionary<string, Object> htmlAttributes)
```

> labelText
>       Type: System.String
>       The label text to display.

Consider to use:

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.JobNo, 
    new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
```

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.labelextensions.labelfor%28v=vs.118%29.aspx for more overloads.